# JQuery Select enclosing div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a way to select the inner class so for example if I use

```
 $('.outer :text').bind("change keyup", function () {
       $(this).removeClass("inner").addClass("newclass");
  });
```

how would i select the inner class that wraps the text input that has been changed?

```
<div class="outer">
         <div class="inner">
               <input type="text">
       </div>
          <div class="inner">
               <input type="text">
       </div>
          <div class="inner">
               <input type="text">
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `:text` selector is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
$( '.outer' ).on( 'change', ':text', function () {
    $( this ).closest( '.inner' ).toggleClass( 'inner newClass' );
});
```